# Inequality of reciprocal functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
Simplify[1/(1/a + 1/b)]
```

{ (a b)/(a + b) }

That doesn't look right. The given function has an infinite term for `a = 0` and one for `b = 0`, while the result has one for `(a + b) = 0`. So that's probably the reason why:

```
a b/(a + b) === 1/(1/a + 1/b)
```

{ False }

though only a minute ago it Simplified it that way! Also

```
Simplify[1/(1/x)]
```

{ x }

seems to disregard the `1/0` case. Can anybody get me out of my confusion?

Comment: `a b/(a + b) === 1/(1/a + 1/b)` returns `False` because they are not structurally the same (which is what `SameQ[]` checks for). As for your actual question, *Mathematica* returns what is called a "generically correct" answer; see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html) for details.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the math itself a bit. The general notion you are missing is that 1/inf=0 , so 1/(1/0)=1/inf=0. There is absolutely no problem in simplifying 1/(1/x)=x. The simplification in the first case are also equivalent when you plug in zeros, for a=0, the first is 1/(inf+1/b)=1/inf=0, and the second is 0*b/(0+b)=0. So you are simply reasoning wrongfully about these "boundary cases".

Comment: @jVincent - I know that, thanks. I was just wondering if MMA keeps track of every element in the equation to determine the domain of the function as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FullSimplify` when testing equality:

```
x = 1/(1/a + 1/b)
Simplify[x]
FullSimplify[% == x]
```

[image]

Comment: Simplify[% == x] also returns True

Comment: Last item of the Equal docs, Possible Issues, adds FullSimplify. It's not an exact match to your case. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html

Comment: It's circular in this case, but the conclusion is use `Simplify` when testing equality.